# If statement inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress

i made this code to make a "|" appear after my `<li>` element closes, but now i'm triying to make it appear only if its located inside another div, any ideas?. Have tried with if statements , no happy ending.

Source code for closing the `<li>` and adding the "|"

```
function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= '</li>'.'<div id="character" style="display: block; float: left;font-size: 15px;line-height: 15px;margin-top: 10px;">|</div>';
}
```

This is the outcome in html:

```
 <ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-1"></li><div id="character">|</div>
    <li id="menu-2></li> <div id="character">|</div>
       <ul id="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-3></li> <div id="character">|</div>
       </ul>
 </ul>
```

And this is what im trying to reach

```
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-1"></li><div id="character">|</div>
    <li id="menu-2></li> <div id="character">|</div>
      <ul id="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-3></li> <div id="character" style="display:none">|</div>
      </ul>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Please clear it up and mark what is PHP and what is JS code and post some actual HTML code on which the JS should run

Comment: yes please edit your question to mark and explain what you want in PHP and what in JS

Comment: same id for multiple div!!

Comment: @Atanu Saha Yes it's not uncommon. Problem will rise when you want to get the element by the id.

Comment: I would prefer to use class instead of id in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough details to make final answer, but few hints:

1. I added example of if statement in code. In this example it will add | only if $depth > 1 (submenu)

```
function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= '</li>' . ((1 < $depth) ? '<div id="character" style="display: block; float: left;font-size: 15px;line-height: 15px;margin-top: 10px;">|</div>' : '');
}
```

2. Your problem is made up because of incorrect style. It's better to add | through CSS (by background image at least). Or you can add it by jQuery. It will make php code much cleaner, and your problem will be easier to solve.

Comment: but you took out the </li> part

Comment: changed 1 < depth to 1 > depth and worked perfectly.

Comment: cool, so my guessing was right) but anyway i recommend to move such things in css, it will became much easier to manage it

Answer (score 0):

If i get your problem correctly, you can use `'<div id="character" style="display: '.$block.'; ...'`, and then `if (condition) $block='none' else $block='block'`

Comment: hmmm this might work, which condition could i use to check if div is inside "sub-menu" parent?